# How can I turn this array into an ArrayList that does the same thing?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

I want to make turn this program's array into an ArrayList. So far I know that the array will turn into

```
ArrayList<StudentList> list = new ArrayList<StudentList>();
```

and that each list[i] will turn into:

```
list.get(i)
```

however I am not sure what the following line will be in order to satisfy the ArrayList version

```
list[i] = new StudentList();
```

so here is the full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StudentList[] list = new StudentList[5];

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {

        list[i] = new StudentList();

        System.out.println("\nEnter information of Student _" + (i + 1) + "\n");
        list[i].DataUserPrompt();

    }
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {

        list[i].DisplayStudentData();
    }

    File file12 = new File("s_records.txt");

    try {

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file12);

        output.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new StudentList[5]` is an array of size 5, with all values `null`, so you create 5 objects using `new StudentList()` and assign to the 5 array indexes.

However, `new ArrayList()` creates an *empty* list (size 0). Note that `new ArrayList(5)` also creates an empty list, it is just optimized to store 5 elements. So you need to create and *add* 5 objects:

```
List<StudentList> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list.add(new StudentList());
}
```

The above is equivalent to the array code:

```
StudentList[] list = new StudentList[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list[i] = new StudentList();
}
```

In both cases you end up with a `list` of size 5, with 5 objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [add(int index, E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-) to insert an element at the specified position.

So `list[i] = new StudentList();` will become `list.add(i, new StudentList());`.

But in your case the list is not already populated, so you should use [add(E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) otherwise you'll get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the index will be bigger than the current size of the list:

```
list.add(new StudentList());
```

Comment: Don't need `add(index, obj)`. A simple `add(obj)` will do. E.g. you can't do `add(10, obj)` unless the list already has at least 10 objects.

Comment: @Andreas of course. I just converted that statement *exactly* to its list counterpart. Seeing the whole code, you're right, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] So far I know that the array will turn into
>
> ```java
> ArrayList<StudentList> list = new ArrayList<StudentList>();
> ```

Yes, this is correct, but normally you will see `List` instead of `ArrayList`.

```java
List<StudentList> list = new ArrayList<StudentList>();
```

The reason for this, is the concept of [Program to an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). Imagine you want to switch from an `ArrayList` to an other data-type of type `List`.. You easily do it without to worry, if your code is now broken.

---

> however I am not sure what the following line will be in order to satisfy the ArrayList version
>
> ```java
> list[i] = new StudentList();
> ```

Since `list` is now an object, you must interact with it through methods. On oracle's documentation for [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) you will find many of them.

But for this scenario you will need [`add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-). You can look up `E` in the documentation too and it means:

> E - the type of elements in this list

With other words: `E` will be your `StudentList`.

---

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<StudentList> list = new ArrayList<StudentList>();

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {

        list.add(new StudentList());

        System.out.println("\nEnter information of Student _" + (i + 1) + "\n");
        list.get(i).DataUserPrompt();

    }
    for (i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {

        list.get(i).DisplayStudentData();
    }

    File file12 = new File("s_records.txt");

    try {

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file12);

        output.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```